# matches key with value in dictionary

Tags: python, key-value

every key compares with value(you may say there is spelling check betwen key and value).If there are only 2 words mismatch then print the key

input={"their":"thuor","diksha","dijmno"}
output=["their"]

```
def find_correct(words_dict):
    count=0
    final_list=[]
    for key,value in words_dict.items():
        for i in range(len(value)): # this may need adjusting for different length words
            if(value[i]!=key[i]):
                count+=1 
            if(count<=2):
                final_list.append(key)

    return final_list

print(find_correct({"their":"thuor","diksha":"dijmno"}))
```

Comment: I thinky ou want to move `if count <= 2:` outside your inner for-loop.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: With your current setup, during the first few loops of your inner loops, count will always be less then 2, and therefore will always append the key, therefore I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, where you may need to move that `if count <= 2` to outside of the inner for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with list comprehension and sets

```
print([i for i in d if len(set(i) - set(d[i])) == 2])
```